# Compiling C# manually while targetting .NET 3.5 with Roslyn(csc.exe)

Tags: c#, .net, csc

I'm using csc/csc2.exe to manually compile an application. I need to reference .NET 3.5 dlls, however it seems that the compiler automatically adds .NET 4.0 dlls as well (which is causing a conflict).

I'm manually referencing the desired version of mscorlib, and other system dlls. Compilation from within Visual Studio succeeds, however compilation of the same response file manually from command prompt fails.

```
/nostdlib+
/platform:AnyCPU
/errorendlocation
/highentropyva-
/reference:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll"
/reference:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll"
/debug+
/debug:full
/out:obj\Debug\Target.exe
/ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset"
/target:exe
/utf8output
Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
```

I'm getting the following errors for every referenced assembly:

```
error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.dll' and 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.
```

What causes the compiler to include .NET 4.0 dlls, and what can I do to prevent it from including them?

**UPDATE:**
I cannot use MSBUILD, because I already have a response file (not a project file) from an application. The application used an outdated version of a compiler, and I'm trying to replace their compiler with a newer one that supports C#6.
I've successfully done this task with Mono MCS compiler, but cannot get the same to work with Roslyn. I cannot use the MCS compiler, because it doesn't yet support all of C#6 features.

The only way to use MSBUILD would be to parse the response file back into a C# project file. This seems like over-engineering to me.

Comment: Just curious: Why do you use `csc2.exe` and not MSBuild if it builds fine in Visual Studio?

Comment: I have an application that uses an outdated C# compiler. The application produces a response file, and I'm trying to use it with a newer compiler.

Comment: Can you update your question and explain that in some more detail? I am fairly certain there is a better solution either using MSBuild (BTW: MSBuild is open-source now!) or `CodeDom`...

Comment: @ChrFin updated the question, hope that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `/noconfig` option to command line and it should work as expected.

> The /noconfig option tells the compiler not to compile with the
>   csc.rsp file, which is located in and loaded from the same directory
>   as the csc.exe file.
>
> The csc.rsp file references all the assemblies shipped with the .NET
>   Framework. The actual references that the Visual Studio .NET
>   development environment includes depend on the project type.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hww4s6c.aspx)

Usual contents of `csc.rps` (v4.0.30319) :

```
/r:Accessibility.dll
/r:Microsoft.CSharp.dll
/r:System.Configuration.dll
/r:System.Configuration.Install.dll
/r:System.Core.dll
/r:System.Data.dll
/r:System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
/r:System.Data.Linq.dll
/r:System.Data.OracleClient.dll
/r:System.Deployment.dll
/r:System.Design.dll
/r:System.DirectoryServices.dll
/r:System.dll
/r:System.Drawing.Design.dll
/r:System.Drawing.dll
/r:System.EnterpriseServices.dll
/r:System.Management.dll
/r:System.Messaging.dll
/r:System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
/r:System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
/r:System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll
/r:System.Security.dll
/r:System.ServiceModel.dll
/r:System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
/r:System.ServiceProcess.dll
/r:System.Transactions.dll
/r:System.Web.dll
/r:System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll
/r:System.Web.Extensions.dll
/r:System.Web.Mobile.dll
/r:System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll
/r:System.Web.Services.dll
/r:System.Windows.Forms.Dll
/r:System.Workflow.Activities.dll
/r:System.Workflow.ComponentModel.dll
/r:System.Workflow.Runtime.dll
/r:System.Xml.dll
/r:System.Xml.Linq.dll
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Interestingly adding the /noconfig option to the response file does nothing, but adding it to the command line does the trick.